# Selenium browser persists after a test is finished

Tags: selenium, google-chrome, testing, browser

I am using Firefox and the Selenium IDE plugin. I have a test for the login of my application. After the end of the test the browser stays logged in and the session gets reused. Can this be avoided ?

Comment: Did you try to clean cockies in the end?

Answer (score 0):

You need to invoke [`driver.quit()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55138341/should-i-quit-the-browser-after-each-selenium-based-automated-test/55139250#55139250) method within the `tearDown() {}`. Invoking `quit()` *DELETEs* the current browsing session through sending **"quit"** command with **{"flags":["eForceQuit"]}** and finally sends the `GET` request on `/shutdown` *EndPoint*.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium : How to stop geckodriver process impacting PC memory, without calling driver.quit()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47999568/selenium-how-to-stop-geckodriver-process-impacting-pc-memory-without-calling/48003289#48003289)
- [PhantomJS web driver stays in memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45985008/phantomjs-web-driver-stays-in-memory/45985790#45985790)